# Recover data session in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I do not know if what I want to do is possible.

I store data in session in Symfony in my controller:

```
$this->get('session')->set('ticket', $billet);
```

In my twig view, I get the session like this:

```
{{App.request.session.get ("ticket")}}
```

I have the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template .....
>   entity could not be converted to string.

I add this function in my entity:

```
Public function __toString () {
   return $this->getPrenom ();
}
```

It works, the problem is that I can only recover a string field (which is in session), I can not retrieve the other fields.

How do I retrieve some values from the session? is it possible ?

Comment: is $billet an object? if true, and you want to get another $billet properties... what if you do `{{App.request.session.get("ticket").anotherProperty}}`?

Comment: I modify my comment, it works well except for the date field. I can not apply the filter on. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access another `$billet` properties, you can:

```
{{App.request.session.get("ticket").anotherProperty}}
```

If field is a date, you can format as:

```
{{ App.request.session.get("ticket").myDateProperty|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Or whatever format you like.

Answer (score 0):

We can access directly the ticket from the session with a shorter syntax as recommended in the symfony documentation.

```
{{ app.session.get("ticket") }}
```